# Java Simple Simulator

Tags: java, user-interface, radio-button, actionlistener, buttongroup

I'm trying to make a sort of simple soccer simulator. This is the code I created after watching tutorials and i know its pretty bad. All i want to do is add a value to the team, like 1 for the best team and 10 for the worst, and when i click simulate a pop up would show up telling me which team would win given the teams value. But i cant figure out how to do it.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;



public class sim extends JPanel {

  public sim() {
    // JFrame constructor
      super(true);

    JRadioButton chelsea, arsenal, chelsea2, arsenal2;

    this.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,0));

    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
    ButtonGroup group2 = new ButtonGroup();

    // takes image and saves it the the variable
    Icon a = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("a.PNG"));
    Icon c = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("c.JPG"));


    chelsea = new JRadioButton("Chelsea",c);
    chelsea.setHorizontalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);
    chelsea.setVerticalTextPosition(AbstractButton.BOTTOM);

    arsenal = new JRadioButton("Arsenal",a);
    arsenal.setHorizontalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);
    arsenal.setVerticalTextPosition(AbstractButton.BOTTOM);

    group.add(chelsea);
    group.add(arsenal);

    JLabel label = new JLabel("");
    TitledBorder titled = new TitledBorder("Team 1");
    label.setBorder(titled);

    chelsea.setBorder(titled);
    arsenal.setBorder(titled);

    JButton button = new JButton("Simulate");
    button.setHorizontalAlignment(JButton.CENTER);
    add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    chelsea2 = new JRadioButton("Chelsea",c);
    chelsea2.setHorizontalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);
    chelsea2.setVerticalTextPosition(AbstractButton.BOTTOM);

    arsenal2 = new JRadioButton("Arsenal",a);
    arsenal2.setHorizontalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);
    arsenal2.setVerticalTextPosition(AbstractButton.BOTTOM);

    group2.add(chelsea2);
    group2.add(arsenal2);

    JLabel label2 = new JLabel("");
    TitledBorder titled2 = new TitledBorder("Team 2");
    label2.setBorder(titled2);

    chelsea2.setBorder(titled);
    arsenal2.setBorder(titled);

    add(label);
    add(chelsea);
    add(arsenal);

    add(button);

    add(chelsea2);
    add(arsenal2);

    HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();
    chelsea.addActionListener(handler);
  }

  private class HandlerClass implements ActionListener
  {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {

          //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, String.format("%s",     e.getActionCommand()));

      }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Final");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(1920, 1080);
    frame.setContentPane(new sim());
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: how do you want to add this value ? a random value you mean?

Comment: I want to add a value of 1 to chelsea and a value of 2 to arsenal and when i choose those team then i click the sim button it would show that chelsea would win since they had a better value.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly capitalize the name of your class always in Java, then check this code :

```
public class Sim extends JPanel {

    public Sim() {
        // JFrame constructor
        super(true);

        JRadioButton chelsea, arsenal, chelsea2, arsenal2;

        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,0));

        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        ButtonGroup group2 = new ButtonGroup();

        // takes image and saves it the the variable
        Icon a = new ImageIcon("/home/mehdi/Pictures/ICONS/Test/1.png");
        Icon c = new ImageIcon("/home/mehdi/Pictures/ICONS/Test/2.png");


        chelsea = new JRadioButton("Chelsea",c);
        chelsea.setHorizontalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);
        chelsea.setVerticalTextPosition(AbstractButton.BOTTOM);

        arsenal = new JRadioButton("Arsenal",a);
        arsenal.setHorizontalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);
        arsenal.setVerticalTextPosition(AbstractButton.BOTTOM);

        group.add(chelsea);
        group.add(arsenal);

        final JLabel label = new JLabel("");
        TitledBorder titled = new TitledBorder("Team 1");
        label.setBorder(titled);

        chelsea.setBorder(titled);
        arsenal.setBorder(titled);

        JButton button = new JButton("Simulate");
        button.setHorizontalAlignment(JButton.CENTER);
        add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        chelsea2 = new JRadioButton("Chelsea",c);
        chelsea2.setHorizontalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);
        chelsea2.setVerticalTextPosition(AbstractButton.BOTTOM);

        arsenal2 = new JRadioButton("Arsenal",a);
        arsenal2.setHorizontalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);
        arsenal2.setVerticalTextPosition(AbstractButton.BOTTOM);

        group2.add(chelsea2);
        group2.add(arsenal2);

        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("");
        TitledBorder titled2 = new TitledBorder("Team 2");
        label2.setBorder(titled2);

        chelsea2.setBorder(titled);
        arsenal2.setBorder(titled);

        add(label);
        add(chelsea);
        add(arsenal);

        add(button);

        add(chelsea2);
        add(arsenal2);

        button.addActionListener(new HandlerClass(label));
    }

    private class HandlerClass implements ActionListener{

        final JLabel label;
        public HandlerClass(JLabel label){
             this.label = label;
        }
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            label.setText("SSSSSSSSSSSSSsssss");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Something");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Final");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(1920, 1080);
        frame.setContentPane(new Sim());
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: How would i make it so when a team in group 1 and a team in group 2  were chosen then i click the sim button it would show that the team with the high value would win?

Comment: firstly make the button disable by default : button.setEnabled(false);
write actionListener on clicking on the team and check inside that listener if the teams have pairly choosen then if yes button.setEnabled(true) and manage what should have happen when user clicks the button